# Finding primes $p$ such that $5^{p^2} + 1 \equiv 0 (\mod p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all the prime numbers $p$ such that $5^{p^2} + 1 \equiv 0 (\mod p)$

Could you give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: It's also true for some composite numbers ($9, 21, 27,...$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transform to ${5^{p}}^2=-1 \pmod p$, thus $5^{2p^2}=1 \pmod p$. Thus, the order of $5$ modulo $p$ belongs to the set $\{2,p,2p,2p^2,1 \}$. 
In the first case, $5^2=1 \pmod p$ thus $p\mid 24$ implying $p=2,3$ give solutions.

If order is $p$, then $5^p=1\pmod p$ implying ${5^{p}}^2=1 \pmod p$ but we already know $5^{p^2}=-1 \pmod p$, thus subtracting we get $2=0 \pmod p$ implying $p=2$ again.

If order is $2p$, by Lagrange's order theorem, you have $2p \mid p-1$ a contradiction, and silimiarly the case when order is $2p^2$ implies $2p^2 \mid p-1$ another contradiction.

Finally the trivial case when order is $1$ implies $4=0\pmod p$ which gives $p=2$ once again.

Thus the only solutions are $p=2,3$

Comment: The order of $5$ modulo $p$ could also be $1$ (e.g., $p=2$)

Comment: Sorry i"ll edit that

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By Fermat's little theorem, $5^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, so $5^{p^2-1}=(5^{p-1})^{p+1}\equiv1\pmod p$,

so $5^{p^2}\equiv5\pmod p$.